# Bug in Vlookup Excel Function?

Tags: excel-formula

It seems to me that Excel (2016) might have a bug while using Vlookup.

it appears that the char "~" produces a fail in Vlookup, according yo the following:[the range B1:B7 is defined as "T_Paths" and the formula in each cell in range C1 is VLOOKUP(B1,T_paths,1,False) etc. It works fine for all, except when char ~ appears in a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOfmx.png)

Comment: your question is.. how to solve this.. or ..?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use ~~ (meaning substitute one "~" for "~~") in he search term B1. This is due to the fact that ~ is taken as a wildchar (as * is).